# Generate sequence diagram from flow of events

Tags: javascript, uml, modeling, visual-paradigm, rup

I'm modeling a web page and using Visual Paradigm. I can generate sequence diagram but with the flow of events. Now I need model sequence diagram, but with more objects than system. Unfortunately VP does not allow me change the control "system" or add more objects to use in the details of flow of events. Is there a way for generate sequence diagram with more lifetime or objects than "system" ?

[image]